# IP Blocked in UFW, yet continue to see failed password attempts in auth.log

Tags: ufw

```
sudo ufw deny from 182.100.67.120
sudo service ufw restart
```

Yet, continuous entries in `/var/log/auth.log`

```
Feb 18 03:40:01 service sshd[2729]: Failed password for root from 182.100.67.120 port 51942 ssh2
```

If the IP is banned in UFW, why it is still getting into ssh login?

Comment: Try " sudo ufw status verbose " and past the output

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.  Since port 22 is already open from anywhere, to block an IP to port 22, the `deny` entry has to go above the `allow` `anywhere` entry in UFW list.  So the right command is (just inserting to the top of the list) :

```
sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 182.100.67.120
sudo service ufw restart
```

But before this, first I had to delete the deny entry using:

```
sudo ufw status numbered
```

Get the serial number of the previously entered `deny` entry for the above port, then

```
sudo ufw delete <serial number >
```